# How to validate DB Users/logins across Availability Group by script

Tags: sql-server

How to validate DB users in AG Groups across nodes by script.
Please help me, any one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"? What does that involve? And have you made any attempt at doing this yourself (like searching for available solutions over the Internet, for instance)?

Comment: Also, is this, by any chance, your question: [validate database users within an AG across its nodes in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48536914/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this addin (AG Addin) for SMSS](https://www.sqlskills.com/free-tools/ssms-availability-group-add-in/), it copies:

- User-defined Server Roles
- Server Logins and Permissions
- Linked Servers
- SQL Server Agent Operators
- SQL Server Agent Alerts
- SQL Server Agent Jobs